# std::string gets corrupted/change structure when passed to a library

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2012 for a project and a build I made myself of Log4cxx for logging purposes. Both projects are built in Debug x64 and (I believe) linked properly.

Platform toolset for both projects is Visual Studio 2012 (v110), Runtime Library is Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd), Log4cxx is created and linked as a dynamic library (.dll).

Consider the following:

```
std::string szTestString = "Hello World!";
DOMConfigurator::configure(szTestString); // Call to Log4cxx.dll
```

While debugging, just before getting in that function, this is the value of szTestString:

[image: String on my project's side]

So far so good. Now I step into the function:

```
void DOMConfigurator::configure(const std::string& filename)
{
    File file(filename);
    DOMConfigurator().doConfigure(file, LogManager::getLoggerRepository());
}
```

And when looking at filename...

[image]

That's obviously not right.

If I step once forward, I get an error:

> Unhandled exception at at 0x000007FEFD6FBDED in SampleProject.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::length_error at memory location 0x000000000030F110.

What could be causing the change in std::string interpretation?

EDIT: currently I added a wrapper to Log4cxx to take char* instead of std::string and it did the trick. The question still stands however.

Comment: We'd need a [mcve] to be able to tell what's wrong. Are all libraries built with the exact same runtime library settings? Are you using static or shared runtime?

Comment: I don't think there is a standard application binary interface (ABI) that would allow a C++ object to be passed to a DLL unless they were compiled with the same compiler and same compiler options, the C++ standard doesn't take it into consideration i.e. the internal representation of std::string is allowed to be different between implementations of the STL and how it's compiled down to binary code by a compiler.

Comment: Possibly a difference in calling conventions, or your project and the DLL are each using different versions of the C++ library.  Did you link either of these projects against the static C++ runtime?

Comment: I added information on the build options near the top. Please tell me if I should add more details (and where to find those).

Comment: It might be worth checking that your project is actually loading the correct version of the DLL.  _i.e_ if you linked these projects with multithreaded debug runtime, and then you inadvertently loaded a release build of the DLL that links against the non-debug runtime.

Comment: @paddy Good idea, however Dependency Walker tells me that my .exe references the proper debug DLL.

Answer (score 1):

This problem generally occurs when library is compiled in "Release" mode and you are trying to run application in "Debug" mode.

Keep both the components i.e., DLL and Application in same mode (Either Release or Debug).
Make sure that "Code Generation" property value for both DLL and Application are same.